# maven-enunciate-plugin on java 1.8 as apt now removed from latest JDK (i.e. java annotation processing tool)

Tags: java, maven, annotations, apt, enunciate

**Question is how to get  java 1.8 and maven-enunciate-plugin to work together ?**

With maven plugin `org.codehaus.enunciate version 1.29` and OSX JDK `1.7.0_25` all is good. 
Enunciate depends on `apt` and I see this runtime warning in  `1.7.0_25`

> [INFO] invoking enunciate:generate step...
>
> warning: The apt tool and its associated API are planned to be removed
>   in the next major JDK release.  These features have been superseded by
>   javac and the standardized annotation processing API,
>   javax.annotation.processing and javax.lang.model.  Users are
>   recommended to migrate to the annotation processing features of javac;
>   see the javac man page for more information.

When change to `1.8.0_05` build fails ...

`apt` is indeed gone, hence runtime errors regarding `com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessorFactory` not found.

> mvn  install  -pl myProject -e -X

...

```
<snip>
urls[46] = file:/Users/k1/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/enunciate-xml/1.29/enunciate-xml-1.29.jar
urls[47] = file:/Users/k1/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/enunciate-java-client/1.29/enunciate-java-client-1.29.jar
urls[48] = file:/Users/k1/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/enunciate-c/1.29/enunciate-c-1.29.jar
urls[49] = file:/Users/k1/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/enunciate-obj-c/1.29/enunciate-obj-c-1.29.jar
urls[50] = file:/Users/k1/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/enunciate-csharp/1.29/enunciate-csharp-1.29.jar
urls[51] = file:/Users/k1/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/enunciate-ruby/1.29/enunciate-ruby-1.29.jar
urls[52] = file:/Users/k1/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/enunciate-php/1.29/enunciate-php-1.29.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:165)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mirror/apt/AnnotationProcessorFactory
    at org.codehaus.enunciate.DocsMojo.loadMavenSpecificEnunciate(DocsMojo.java:107)
    at org.codehaus.enunciate.ConfigMojo.execute(ConfigMojo.java:326)
    at org.codehaus.enunciate.DocsMojo.execute(DocsMojo.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessorFactory
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
    ... 24 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Comment: Many maven plugins are not yet ported to work with 1.8. Best to post this to the relevant JIRA project at codehaus.

Comment: Cheers - added my own answer after looking at JIRA at codehaus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT July 2015:
This original question and this answer were written when Enunciate 1.x was the latest. Though 1.x still doesn't support java 1.8, as described in comments below, 2.0 M-1, now does have limited support for java 1.8, i.e. documentation generated but not API modules.**

As recommended by @bmargulies I looked at JIRA page (which I guess I should have done in first place!)
Paraphrasing [JIRA ENUNCIATE-701](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ENUNCIATE-701?jql=project%20=%20ENUNCIATE%20AND%20text%20~%20jdk8)

*" No timeline yet for Enunciate / JDK8 compatibility."*

Enunciate has moved to Github; the issue there is [#68](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/issues/68)

Comment: First milestone of Enunciate 2 is out now.

Comment: @Wivani Issue #68 regarding JDK8  seems still open ? Is that just a oversight as I happily read at https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/releases/tag/v2.0.0-M.1 that Support for Java 8 is included (albeit that Milestone 1 still doesn't include support for client-side libraries yet)

Comment: I'm just reporting ;-) Feel free to suggest to Stoicflame at github to close the issue but maybe he's not closing until later on (with the extra support etc like you mention)

Comment: I'm facing this issue in my maven plugin. Was this issue resolved? What need to do to resolve this issue in my local Maven plugin.

Comment: any one used java8 with Enunciate

Comment: Seems like they renamed the plugin to com.webcohesion.enunciate:enunciate-maven-plugin. Here's a link to Maven Central repo: https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.webcohesion.enunciate/enunciate-maven-plugin